# How can you set the value of a target cell in google sheets within a forEach loop in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a script that searches through a sheet, finds rows that meet 7 parameters, returns those rows' data, and sends an email to the address in each of the matching rows. As part of this process, I want to update the cell value for 'Date of last contact' to the date the email is sent (that part's not hard). I'm struggling to get the A1 notation of the cell containing the date of last contact, which I believe I need in order to use the setValue() method. Here's the relevant parts of the code:

```
function sendFollowUps () {
  // Gets data from defined range of active sheet
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test List').getRange(2,1,152,12).getValues()

  // User-defined cutoff date, everything on or before will be contacted
  var cutoffDate = new Date('11/10/2021')
  console.log('Cutoff date is: ' + cutoffDate)

  // selects and returns only firms that haven't been met, schedule, or declined and have a date of last contact on or before the cutoffDate
  var filteredRows = rows.filter(function(row) {
    if (row[10] && row[10] != 'Met' && row[10] != 'Responded' && row[10] != 'Warm' && row[10] != 'Scheduled' && row[10] != 'Declined' && row[11] <= cutoffDate) {
      return row
    }
  })

  // for each firm returned by filteredRows, pulls email, firstName of investor, and firmName
  filteredRows.forEach(function(row) {
    var email = row[6]
    var firstName = row[4].split(' ')[0]
    var firmName = row[0]
    var sendToEmails = ['...']

    // Customized email message with firstName, firmName updated per investor
    var messageSubject = '...'
    var messageBody = `...`

    // Adds investor email to recipient list
    sendToEmails.push(email)

    // Formats recipient list to CSV string
    sendToEmails.join(',')

    // Sends email with customized firstName and firmName to email in row
    GmailApp.sendEmail(sendToEmails, messageSubject, messageBody, {'from': 'me@email.com'})

    followUpEmails.push(email)
}
```

I've tried just setting `row[11] = sendDate` within the forEach loop, but that doesn't actually update the cell value in the sheet. I've also tried using `SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Test List').getRange(row[11])`, `SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Test List').getActiveCell()`, and `SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Test List').getCurrentCell(row[11])`, no joy with those either.

How can I go about getting the A1 notation for the row[11] cell in order to use setValue method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A1 notation will be almost impossible to get because you `filter`  first. This is already mentioned in the previous answer. However, you can modify the array and then `.setValues()` the modified array on the entire range:

```
const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test List').getRange(2,1,152,12);
const rows = range.getValues();
```

Then inside `.forEach()`,

```
row[11]=sentDate;
```

Outside `forEach()`:

```
range.setValues(rows);
```

Note that this replaces all the formulas(if any) with values.

Comment: @BryceCollison Great! Consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of this post.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is not working correctly because you cannot compare dates like that since `var cutoffDate = new Date('11/10/2021')`

```
var filteredRows = rows.filter(function(row) {
    if (row[10] && row[10] != 'Met' && row[10] != 'Responded' && row[10] != 'Warm' && row[10] != 'Scheduled' && row[10] != 'Declined' && row[11] <= cutoffDate) {
      return row
    }
  })
```

Also using the filter like you have now has broken the continuity between the index in the foreach and the indexing of the values in the dataset.  I would not filter the data and instead perform the data search as part of the forEach

I think you will be better off to do it this way:

```
function sendFollowUps() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Test List');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, 152, 12).getValues()
  var cutoffDate = new Date('11/10/2021').valueOf();
  vs.forEach(row => {
    if (row[10] && row[10] != 'Met' && row[10] != 'Responded' && row[10] != 'Warm' && row[10] != 'Scheduled' && row[10] != 'Declined' && new Date(row[11]).valueOf() <= cutoffDate) {
      var email = row[6];
      var firstName = row[4].split(' ')[0];
      var firmName = row[0];
      var sendToEmails;
      var messageSubject;
      var messageBody;
      sendToEmails.push(email)
      sendToEmails.join(',')
      GmailApp.sendEmail(sendToEmails, messageSubject, messageBody, { 'from': 'me@email.com' });
      followUpEmails.push(email)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The date comparison works fine, and the script performs as intended as far as identifying rows matching all conditions and sending personalized messages to the address stored in each row. The functionality I'd like to add is automatically updating the value of date of last contact (row[11]) for each row that meets the requirements at runtime.

Comment: Yeah well that is a problem since you have filter the connection between the data start row of 2 and the index of the  2d array of data.  Some how you need to keep track of what data rows  have been removed.

Comment: I hear what you are saying about the date but I just happen to believe that you are wrong.  Because I know you cannot compare dates that way.

Comment: The filtered, or removed, rows are stored in the filterdRows var and looped through to perform the function of the script. So no mutation is happening to the rows var, it's pretty much equivalent to mapping into the filteredRows var. Only thing I'm stuck on is being able to access and mutate one cell in each row in filteredRows var

Comment: As far as the date comparison goes, it does work since the stored date in the sheet is a UTC object, as is the cutoffDate. Built-in capability in JS to compare Date objects with boolean operators

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but that refactored code is still missing the functionality to update the date of last contact value of each row where conditions are met

Comment: That's the whole point you can't compare objects numerically

Comment: This has moved pretty well away from the initial question. Do you know of a way to mutate a cell value inside a loop, or is this not possible without a verbose definition of the A1 notation cell to be edited?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by mutate

Comment: Change the value of the cell from the original date of last contact (let's say 11/1/2021) to the date the script runs (let's say 12/10/2021)

Comment: setValue() method of Class Range